# ¿Cómo puedo enviar el usuario guardado dentro de passport desde el servidor backend, hacia el servidor frontend de React?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, login, backend, passport

Estoy utilizando un servidor backend que maneja la lógica junto con un servidor frontend en React. Lo que necesito es enviar el usuario logueado desde el servidor backend hacia el servidor frontend.
Pero primero voy a explicar como funciona mi flujo de código de forma básica una vez que el usuario se loguea.

Entonces, a partir de que el usuario ingresa, passport hace sus cosas y luego almacena el usuario.
Código de passport:

```
passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'celnumber',
  passwordField: 'celnumber',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, names, celnumber, done) => {
  const user = await userController.findByCelNumber(celnumber);
  if(!user) {
    return done(null, false, localStorage.setItem('failureMessage', 'El número ingresado no existe.'));
  }
  localStorage.setItem('successMessage', 'Te has logueado satisfactoriamente.')
  return done(null, user);
}));
```

Una vez que el logueo se haya realizado correctamente, se redirecciona al servidor frontend a partir del successRedirect:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local-signin",
  {
    successRedirect: "http://localhost:3001",
    failureRedirect: "/users/login",
    passReqToCallback: true
  }
));
```

**Aclaración**: El `successRedirect: "http://localhost:3001"`, unicamente está ahi para que passport no me tire ningún error, pero realmente no lo estoy utilizando para nada. La redirección la estoy realizando a partir de un window.location.href mostrado a continuación.

Y finalmente, viene a mi custom hook `useFormHelper` en donde redirecciono al servidor frontend para que renderize la página inicial.

```
if(type === "login") {
  e.preventDefault();
  await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/login', form).then(async function (response){
      alert("Logueo completado satisfactoriamente.")
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:3001/";
  });
}
```

**Mi pregunta entonces es**, como puedo enviarle el usuario logueado dentro de passport desde el propio servidor backend hacia el servidor frontend de React?

Vi en una publicación similar que podia usar mi windows.location.href y pasarle el usuario tal como: `window.location.href = "http://localhost:3001/" + user`, pero en teoria no es muy seguro.
Tambien se me ocurrio enviarle el usuario a través del succesRedirect pero no dispongo de un 'req' como para enviarle el req.user de passport. `successRedirect: "http://localhost:3001" + req.user,`

Espero haberme explicado correctamente, cualquier cosa no duden en consultarme. Gracias.